# Error in configuring Solr 8.1.1 with Sitecore 9.3

Tags: solr, indexing

I am currently configuring Solr 8.1.1 in Sitecore 9.3, But I'm unable to view the `Indexing Manager` under CMS->Control panel, instead we are getting the below error:

```
    [InvalidOperationException: Could not find property 'indexAllFields' on object of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +2356
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +109
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +947
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +309
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Forms.IndexingManagerWizard.BuildIndexes() +167
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Forms.IndexingManagerWizard.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +89
```

Please find the below `Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` that has been used:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" search:require="solr">
    <contentSearch>
      <!-- Configuration sections for indexes -->
      <indexConfigurations>    
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">                                
          <initializeOnAdd>false</initializeOnAdd>    
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">               
            <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
              <typeMatch typeName="guidCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]"     fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="textCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_txm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="stringCollection"   type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="intCollection"      type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"    fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="guid"               type="System.Guid"                                        fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="id"                 type="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel"                  fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="shortid"            type="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel"             fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="string"             type="System.String"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="text"               type="System.String"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_t"   cultureFormat="_{1}"                  settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="int"                type="System.Int32"                                       fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="bool"               type="System.Boolean"                                     fieldNameFormat="{0}_b"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="datetime"           type="System.DateTime"                                    fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdt" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="long"               type="System.Int64"                                       fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="float"              type="System.Single"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_tf"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="double"             type="System.Double"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_td"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="stringArray"        type="System.String[]"                                    fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="intArray"           type="System.Int32[]"                                     fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="datetimeArray"      type="System.DateTime[]"                                  fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="datetimeCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="coordinate"         type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data" fieldNameFormat="{0}_rpt"                      settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
            </typeMatches>                  
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="__created_by"         returnType="string" />
              <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate"   returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss'Z'" />
              <field fieldName="__smallupdateddate"   returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss'Z'" />
              <field fieldName="__workflow_state"     returnType="string" />
              <field fieldName="extension"            returnType="text" />
              <field fieldName="title"                returnType="text" />
              <field fieldName="type"                 returnType="text" />
            </fieldNames>  
            <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="checkbox"                                                                                                 returnType="bool"             />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="date|datetime"                                                                                            returnType="datetime"         />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="html|rich text|single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo|image|reference"                                returnType="text"             />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="word document"                                                                                            returnType="text"             />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="integer"                                                                                                  returnType="long"             />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="number"                                                                                                   returnType="float"            />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist"                                                                           returnType="string"           />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|tree list|treelistex|tree list|multilist with search|treelist with search"   returnType="stringCollection" />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list"                                                                   returnType="stringCollection" />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree"                                                                  returnType="stringCollection" />
            </fieldTypes>
          </fieldMap>

          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">               
          <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>               
            <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
              <BucketFolderTemplateId>{ADB6CA4F-03EF-4F47-B9AC-9CE2BA53FF97}</BucketFolderTemplateId>
            </exclude>

            <checkTemplateInheritance>true</checkTemplateInheritance>                                      
            <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">
              <__Created>{25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497}</__Created>
              <__DefaultWorkflow>{CA9B9F52-4FB0-4F87-A79F-24DEA62CDA65}</__DefaultWorkflow>
              <__Lock>{001DD393-96C5-490B-924A-B0F25CD9EFD8}</__Lock>
              <__LongDescription>{577F1689-7DE4-4AD2-A15F-7FDC1759285F}</__LongDescription>
              <__Originator>{F6D8A61C-2F84-4401-BD24-52D2068172BC}</__Originator>                
              <__SourceItem>{19B597D3-2EDD-4AE2-AEFE-4A94C7F10E31}</__SourceItem>
              <__Updated>{D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522}</__Updated>                  
            </exclude>    
            <fields hint="raw:AddExcludedSpecialField">
              <remove type="both">AllTemplates</remove>
              <remove type="both">Created</remove>
              <remove type="both">Editor</remove>
              <remove type="both">Hidden</remove>                  
            </fields>    
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">                 
                <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing"/>
              </field>
              <field fieldName="calculateddimension"            returnType="stringCollection">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CalculatedDimension,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>               
              <field fieldName="ispointofinterest"              returnType="bool"            >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsPointOfInterest, Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
              <field fieldName="coordinate"                     returnType="coordinate"      >Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.ComputedFields.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</field>                
              <field fieldName="_readaccess">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ReadAccess, Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>                
              <field fieldName="__solr_norm_field_name"         returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.FieldNames.TypeResolving.Index.ComputedFields.NormalizedTemplateFieldName,Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</field>
              <field fieldName="__solr_field_type"              returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.FieldNames.TypeResolving.Index.ComputedFields.TemplateFieldType,Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>    
          <mediaIndexing hint="skip">
            <mimeTypes>
              <excludes>
                <mimeType>*</mimeType>
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
                <mimeType type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemHtmlTextExtractor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">text/html</mimeType>
                <mimeType>text/plain</mimeType>
              </includes>
            </mimeTypes>
            <extensions>
              <excludes>
                <extension>*</extension>
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <extension>rtf</extension>
                <extension>odt</extension>
                <extension>doc</extension>
                <extension>dot</extension>
                <extension>docx</extension>                    
              </includes>
            </extensions>
          </mediaIndexing>    
          <virtualFields type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFieldProcessorMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <processors hint="raw:AddFromConfiguration">
              <add fieldName="daterange" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.DateRangeFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <add fieldName="_lastestversion" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.LatestVersionFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <add fieldName="updateddaterange" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.UpdatedDateRangeFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <add fieldName="_url" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.UniqueIdFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <add fieldName="_fullpath" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.VirtualFields.FullPathFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <add fieldName="parsedcreatedby_s" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.CreatedByFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
            </processors>
          </virtualFields>    
          <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <param desc="id">defaultFieldReaderMap</param>
            <mapFieldByTypeName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldTypeName">
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checkbox"                                             fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.CheckboxFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="date|datetime"                                        fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DateFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="image"                                                fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.ImageFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo"           fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="integer"                                              fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="number"                                               fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.PrecisionNumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="html|rich text"                                       fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.RichTextFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="multilist with search|treelist with search"           fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DelimitedListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|treelistex|tree list"    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist"                       fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list"               fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NameValueListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree|reference"    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.LookupFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="attachment|frame|rules|tracking|thumbnail"            fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="file|security|server file|template field source|link" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
            </mapFieldByTypeName>
          </fieldReaders>    
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Converters.SolrIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <converters hint="raw:AddConverter">
              <converter handlesType="System.Guid"                                                          typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldGuidValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel"                                    typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel"                               typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldShortIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="System.DateTime"                                                      typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldUTCDateTimeValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="System.DateTimeOffset"                                                typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeOffsetValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="System.TimeSpan"                                                      typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldTimeSpanValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"        typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldSitecoreItemIDValueConvertor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
              </converter>
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"  typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Converters.SolrIndexFieldSitecoreItemUniqueIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
              </converter>
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ItemUri, Sitecore.Kernel"                               typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Globalization.Language, Sitecore.Kernel"                     typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldLanguageValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="System.Globalization.CultureInfo"                                     typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldCultureInfoValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Version, Sitecore.Kernel"                               typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldVersionValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel"                              typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDatabaseValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"          typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexableIdConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"    typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexableUniqueIdConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data"  typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldCoordinateValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
            </converters>
          </indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>    
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Mapping.SolrDocumentPropertyMapper, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">              
            <objectFactory type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapperObjectFactory, Sitecore.ContentSearch">

            </objectFactory>
          </indexDocumentPropertyMapper>    
          <documentBuilderType>Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilder, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</documentBuilderType>

          <defaultSearchSecurityOption ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSearchSecurityOption" />

          <enableReadAccessIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/enableReadAccessIndexing" />
         <!-- <solrHttpWebRequestFactory type="HttpWebAdapters.HttpWebRequestFactory, SolrNet" />-->
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>            
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
    <services>         
      <configurator type= "Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.DependencyInjection.ContentSearchServicesConfigurator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
    </services>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeScheduler, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </initialize>
      <contentSearch.translateQuery>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.TranslateQuery.ApplySolrTranslation, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
      </contentSearch.translateQuery>
      <contentSearch.formatQueryFieldValue>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.FormatQueryFieldValue.ApplyFieldMappingRule, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
      </contentSearch.formatQueryFieldValue>
      <contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.ResolveCoreNames, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.PopulateFields, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Factories.DefaultPopulateHelperFactory" />
        </processor>
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.ReInitializeIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
      </contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema>
    </pipelines>
    <scheduling>
      <agent type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IsSolrAliveAgent, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" />
      <agent type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" method="Run" interval="00:01:00" />
    </scheduling>
    <settings>      
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Provider" value="Solr" />         
      <setting name="ContentSearch.DefaultIndexConfigurationPath" value="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />         
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" value="https://localhost:8983/solr" />          
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ConnectionTimeout" value="-1" />             
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.SendPostRequests" value="false" />       
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.EnableHttpCache" value="true" />          
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Update.BatchModeEnabled" value="true" />    
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Update.BatchSize" value="500" />    
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ParallelIndexInitialization.MaxThreadLimit" value="6" />    
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.SuggestHandler" value="/suggest" />    
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.SpellCheckHandler" value="/spell" />    
      <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.SolrSchemaClass" value="managed" />

    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Have verified all the configurations related to Solr and it looks good. So, it would be helpful if you could suggest me on how this indexing manager is working and what are the configurations needed to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sitecore 9.3, it is subjected to add the below lines to make indexAllFields true under
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.MediaFramework.Brightcove.config

```
<documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"><IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields</documentOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing that extra closing field tag `</field>` within the `<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">` block. Looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your error might happen due to an invalid config file as some default fields were removed. After comparing your config to the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` from 9.3 sitecore vanilla it seems that there are quite a lot of differences in the sections `<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">`(removing for example _content field) and `<exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">` (removing fields which shouldn't be indexed).

I would suggest to verify if removing all those fields is intentional (maybe to speed up indexing) as it might affect your content search aswell.